# Safari top, left transition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have manage to make an custom cursor with the use of an div. Everything works on chrome and firefox, but not in Safari. I am using a `transition` for the effect.

In Safari it looks like they do not update at the same time (when the transition for `left` is done the `top` begins)

```js
  function muisupdate(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 991) {
      if (!e) var e = window.event;
      var mousex = e.pageX - 50;
      var mousey = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() - 50;
      $('.cursor').css({
        'top': mousey + 'px',
        'left': mousex + 'px'
      });
      $('body').css('cursor', 'none');
    }
  }

  $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
    muisupdate(e);
  });
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /*border-radius: 100%;
    background:red;*/
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  -moz-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  -o-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  transition-property: left, top;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  --length: 24;
  --offset: -38;
  stroke-dasharray: var(--length) var(--total-length);
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--offset);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5.15"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Working exaple: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tim_bentum/pen/YJOJrM)

Does anyone know how to make it smooth?

**Edit** i have changed the `right`in the `transition` to `top` however this does **not** fix the issue

Comment: It would help to see a working demo.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan iserted into the post

Comment: it looks like `right` should be `top` instead in css transition properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `right` to `top` in css transition properties:

```
-webkit-transition: left right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
-moz-transition: left right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
-o-transition: left right 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
transition-property: left, right;
```

->

```
-webkit-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
-moz-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
-o-transition: left top 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
transition-property: left, top;
```

As you never using the `right` property and instead using `top` which is not used by transitions. And in Safari it just works a bit faster, while on Chrome it looks to be transitioned (when it is not)

Comment: I sow this in your comment and tries how ever it does't work

Comment: @Tim567 Well, I also tried this, and it works. Try decreasing timing to 1s or so

Comment: Thats wierd when i did the chang my self it din't work proper bur by copying yours it workt fine! Thanks

Comment: @Tim567 That's probably because it does not apply to result immediately, you should wait for several seconds after making a change in the editor. Also be aware that in my codepen there is `1s` instead of `0.5s`, that's why it even smoother than yours.

Comment: i did and in my inspector it showt the results too ,must had made an typo